# Selenium Invalid ID session before quit with new chromedriver 121

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I updated the browser and the web driver for selenium to the last version 121.0.6167.85 (Official Build) (x86_64).
And now after a bit 30min more or less all test fail with error:

```
HOOK-ERROR in after_scenario: InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

NOTE:

1. Before the update, all tests passed.
2. The session is not close before the error with web_driver.close() or with web_driver.quit()

Does anybody have the same error? some tips on how to resolve this? There is a timeout for the session? I didn't find anything regarding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your problem, but we also have issue with similar symptoms in our Capyabra-Selenium tests on Ruby on Rails. And looks like Chrome v121 has memory leak, fixed in v122. Try to use v122 from beta channel. [Look at this for details about memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77951450/chromedriver-121-in-selenium-eating-up-memory).