# Chromedriver 121 in Selenium eating up memory

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I truly believe there is some kind of huge memory leak/problem with the ver. 121 chromedriver. I have a web scraping program that runs all day and it has been stable for the past 6 months. I throttle the refresh of the page updates to no faster than 2.5 seconds. Last Wednesday (Jan 31, 2024) my Chrome (Windows 64 bit) updated to version 121. That caused my chromedriver to update to version 121 as well. Within 15 to 20 minutes of running my PowerShell based web scraper I was no longer refreshing at 2.5 seconds. The refresh rate starting increasing in time until the browser would sometimes just hang. I decided to see if this would happen if running Selenium using Firefox or Edge. Both of those ran fine without slowing down.

Next I decided to write a simple PowerShell Selenium script that would go to a website and just refresh the page over and over. When running that in Chrome that would start running really slow as well while it was fine using both Firefox and Edge. So I looked at the built in Chrome Task Manager while the program was running and I could see that the Memory Footprint was going up and up. I then decided to just run Chrome without Selenium using an extension to just refresh the page every 5 seconds. That ran perfectly fine and the Memory Footprint didn't rise.

Again I changed my PowerShell Selenium script to just connect to the website and not do any refreshes through the script. Basically I let the script pause then installed an auto refresh extension on the browser opened by chromedriver. I ran this script side by side with the other being opened by edgedriver. After about one hour the Memory Footprint for the process in Chrome was about 1.4 Gigs while for Edge it was only about 68 Megs.

[Edge vs Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx46V.jpg)

This issue happens for me on 3 different PCs, 2 running Windows 10 the other Windows 11 so I doubt it's something that changed on my PCs. It happened running Selenium version 4.16.2 as well as version 4.17.0. Is this a Selenium issue, a chromedriver issue, or Chrome browser issue, or something on my end? I couldn't find any complaints related to Chrome being run though Selenium, although I did read some about Chrome 121 being slow in general. Should this post be here or on the Selenium issues site?

I will post my script here as well. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

```
# BrowserLoopTest.ps1

# Version 1.0 (05 Feb 2024)
# * Initial version.


<#
To run in ISE or from Powershell prompt
    cd "$($env:UserProfile)\Documents"

        for Chrome
    & '.\Backup\Task Scheduler Tasks\BrowserLoopTest.ps1' -useBrowser 0
        or
        for Edge
    & '.\Backup\Task Scheduler Tasks\BrowserLoopTest.ps1' -useBrowser 1
            or
        for Firefox
    & '.\Backup\Task Scheduler Tasks\BrowserLoopTest.ps1' -useBrowser 2

#>

param(
    [String] $useBrowser
)

$browserType = [System.Convert]::ToInt16($useBrowser)



Function New-BrowserDriver {
    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess,
        ConfirmImpact = 'Low'
    )]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ScriptPath
    )

    $private:result = $null
    Initialize-Selenium -ScriptPath $ScriptPath
    if ($browserType -eq 0) {
        $private:browserOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
    } elseif ($browserType -eq 1) {
        $private:browserOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions
    } elseif ($browserType -eq 2) {
        $private:browserOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions
    }


    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("Create a new instance of the Browser Driver.")) {
        try {
            if ($browserType -eq 0) {
                $private:driver = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($private:browserOptions)
            } elseif ($browserType -eq 1) {
                $private:driver = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver($private:browserOptions)
            } elseif ($browserType -eq 2) {
                $private:driver = New-Object -TypeName OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FireFoxDriver($private:browserOptions)
            }
        } catch {
            $Error[0].Exception.ToString()
            Write-Host " "
            $Error[0].Exception.StackTrace
            Write-Host " "
            $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.StackTrace
            Write-Host " "
            $Error[0].StackTrace
        }
    }

    $private:driver

    <#
    #Use this code to refresh the webpage every 5 seconds

    for ($x=0; $x -lt 1440; $x++) {
        $private:driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.time.gov/")
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
    #>


    #Use this code to just go to the url, then do refreshes to the page
    #using a browser extension
    $private:driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.time.gov/")
    read-host “Press ENTER to continue...”

    $private:driver.Close()
    $private:driver.Quit()
}

Function Initialize-Selenium([string]$ScriptPath) {
    Import-Module "$($ScriptPath)WebDriver.dll"
}


$FolderWithDllsAndBrowserDriverExecutable = "$($env:UserProfile)\Documents\Backup\Task Scheduler Tasks\Library\SeleniumModule\"
New-BrowserDriver -ScriptPath $FolderWithDllsAndBrowserDriverExecutable
```

Comment: Definitely seeing some performance issues on Chrome v121 browser itself (not related to Chromedriver) running SeleniumLibrary with RobotFramework in Fedora 38/39.

One set of suites is taking almost twice as long to run as with Chrome v120 whereas 2 other suites are showing very little difference so it possibly relates to only certain functions/keywords. Suspect some memory leak or resource hogging of some kind but haven't narrowed it down to anything in particular yet.

Expected to see more online about it but perhaps Chrome v121 is still to new to have been adopted by many people yet?

Answer (score 2):

I've been intensively testing chrome 120 VS 121 and the result is following:

- on machine with 4Gb RAM
- using selenium with chromedriver for intensive performance testing scenario

There is significantly more CPU usage for v121 and performance regressions. Measured actions take 100%-200% more time, the difference is only in the browser.

Mind the Y axis

[![CPU usage: Chrome 120 on the left VS 121 on the right][1]][1]

chromedriver was also measured and there is no difference between 120 VS 121, difference is for chrome process only
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4LOo.png

Full investigation details: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JPERF-1457

Comment: I believe this is the issue here: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41494493. It needs more upvotes. Google hasn't even assigned it to somebody yet. You can just refresh a single page and see the memory grow.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm there is memory leak problem with version 121, causing out of memory error and crash the test.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for us, was upgrading to beta versions of chrome and chrome driver. using BETA 122 versions of chrome and chromedriver completely fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes can also confirm that Chrome 122 Beta does not seem to display the same performance issues at the moment (although expectedly, it's less stable) so hopefully by the time it goes stable it will bring back Chrome 120 levels of performance.

Comment: I've run a few tests on Chrome 123 and it still happens (just refresh a single page and watch the memory go up).

Comment: i used 122 chrome and chromedriver. not sure about chrome 123 though.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like there is an issue with the latest stable version of Chrome drive ( 121.0.6167.85 ).
I tested it on version 122 (Beta) and 120, and it is much better.

The good news is that tmw version 122 will be a stable version.